# Is it possible to display a statusbar in Nautilus Files?

Tags: nautilus

Is there any properties available for Nautilus to display a static status bar at the bottom of the gui window, similar as in Windows file manager?

Comment: Do you mean GNOME Shell? See https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/828/bottom-panel/ and https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/

Answer (score 0):

Not natively. If it's the free disk space you want to check, there's [this small extension](https://github.com/benintech/Nautilus-Status-Bar-Replacement) :

[image]